# Call base class overloaded operator from parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

In the following simple structs, p3 inherits from p2.

```
struct p2 {
    double x, y;
    p2(double x, double y) : x(x),y(y){}
    bool operator ==(const p2& b) const{ return x == b.x && y == b.y; }
    bool operator !=(const p2& b) const{ return !(*this == b); }
};

struct p3 : p2 {
    double z;
    p3(double x, double y, double z) : p2(x,y),z(z){}
    bool operator ==(const p3& b) const{ return x == b.x && y == b.y && z == b.z; }
    bool operator !=(const p3& b) const{ return !(*this == b); }
};
```

In the overloaded comparison operators for p3, how can I replace the `x == b.x && y == b.y` part with a call to the overloaded operator from the parent class?

Comment: if you want to call parent's function why you have overloaded it?

Comment: `bool operator ==(const p3& b) const{ return p2::operator==(b) && z == b.z; }`

Comment: @AliKazmi. I don't think you read my question properly, I said the `x == b.x && y == b.y` part, which is only 2/3 of the checks in comparing a p3 object.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks. thats the notation I was after. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool operator==(const p3& b) const
{
    return p2::operator==(b) && z == b.z; 
    //     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the scoping operator `::` in the derived struct

So in your `operator==()` in struct `p3` looks like this:

```
bool operator==(const p3& b) const {
    return p2::operator==(b) && z == b.z;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Piotr got in there first... ;-)